# Is there a name for the "scalar product" in Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

What would be the best term for the same object i.e $(x,y)$. I guess its some kind of bilinear form, but in general it does not obey the parallellogram law hence its not a scalar- or innerproduct.

Its hard to know how one should limit general definition in order not to loose to much.

Comment: bilinear form, sesquilinear form, maybe adding the positive definite

Comment: Do you mean the pairing of a vector with a functional? Or is this some new mapping you have defined?

Comment: @Aweygan I mean the abstact structure on the banach space, but in some sense yes, this will be the stucture in which the linear functinals are expressed in by Rieaz theorem. I guess id say the "map"

Comment: I think you are referring to Hilbert spaces, not Banach spaces. Banach spaces do not have a scalar product.

Comment: @User231241: You should write down the precise properties of your 'object' $(x,y)$. Then, we could give some advice. In particular, do you have $x,y \in X$ or rather $x \in X$, $y \in X^*$?

Comment: @gerw y is in the dual! I completly missed that they are not  self dual..

Comment: @User231241 In that case its just a bilinear map. No special name.

Comment: This is standard notation for the duality pairing between elements in $X$ and $X^*$, and is used in pretty much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the map $(\cdot, \cdot) : X \times X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ defined via
$$(x,y) := y(x)$$
is denoted as *duality map*.

In my opinion, this notion is in particular used if one has a space $Y$ which is isometric to $X^*$, i.e., for the map
$$(x,y) := (I\,y)(x),$$
where $I : Y \to X^*$ is an isometric isomorphism. However, typically one might use acute brackets $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: You have reference where i can read about this definition?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Sorry.

Comment: This is clearly always bilinear, but ill keep the name in mind if I run into it.